# Instance variable value not printing properly

Tags: c++, oop

I am using a constructor to initialize the instance variable. When I print the instance variable it gives wrong output.

```
int main(){
    int k[]={1,2,4};  
    int hs=3;  
    int n=3;  
    priorityq p(k,hs,n);  
    p.printKey();  
}
```

```
class priorityq{  
    int key[];  
    int heapsize;  
    int n;  
public:  
    void printKey();  
    priorityq(int k[],int hs, int ni);  
};
```

```
priorityq::priorityq(int k[],int hs, int ni){  
     for(int i=0;i<ni;i++)  
      key[i]=k[i];  
     heapsize=hs;   
     n=n_i;   
}
void priorityq::printKey(){     
     for(int i=0;i<heap_size;i++)   
       cout<<key[i]<<" ";   
     cout<<endl;    
}
```

I expect output to be 
1 2 4
but am getting 
3 3 4

Comment: or std::priority_queue

Comment: pay attention to your compilers output. `int key[];` as member should trigger an error or at least a warning

Answer (score 5):

Use `std::array` if you are using c++, or better for dynamic-ranged arrays, use `std::vector`. And instead of using `[]`-operator use the `at()` method, which checks for out-of-bound errors:

Edit, there was an error in the constructor

```
int main(){
    std::vector<int> k{1,2,4};  
    int hs=3;  
    int n=3;  
    priorityq p(k,hs,n);  
    p.printKey();  
}
```

..

```
class priorityq{  
    std::vector<int> key;  
    int heapsize;  
    int n;  
public:  
    void printKey();  
    priorityq(std::vector<int>& k,int hs, int ni);  
};
```

..

```
priorityq::priorityq(std::vector<int>& k,int hs, int ni){  
     for(int i=0;i<ni;i++)  
      key.push_back(k.at(i));  
     heapsize=hs;   
     n=n_i;   
}
void priorityq::printKey(){     
     for(int i=0;i<heap_size;i++)   
       cout<<key.at(i)<<" ";   
     cout<<endl;    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't allocate any memory for the class member `key`.

Use `std::vector<int> key;` as the member instead, with a `key.resize(ni);` in your constructor.

Once you have it working, bin the whole thing, and use `std::priority_queue`.